# NVCC Compile Error when calling Eigen function in kernel code

Tags: c++, eigen, nvcc

I am using Eigen 3.3.9 for my project running on Ubuntu 18.04.4. Everything worked well before I tried to modify my project for CUDA support. I've tried cuda/10.0 and cuda/10.2.

My problem occurs when I try to call determinant() for a Eigen Matrix. My compiler produces the following errors.

```
voxelize.cu(301): error: calling a __host__ function("Eigen::MatrixBase< ::Eigen::Matrix<float, (int)3, (int)3, (int)0, (int)3, (int)3> > ::determinant const") from a __global__ function("MeshIterKernel") is not allowed

voxelize.cu(301): error: identifier "Eigen::MatrixBase< ::Eigen::Matrix<float, (int)3, (int)3, (int)0, (int)3, (int)3> > ::determinant const" is undefined in device code

voxelize.cu(301): error: calling a __host__ function("Eigen::MatrixBase< ::Eigen::Matrix<float, (int)3, (int)3, (int)0, (int)3, (int)3> > ::determinant const") from a __global__ function("MeshIterKernel") is not allowed

voxelize.cu(301): error: identifier "Eigen::MatrixBase< ::Eigen::Matrix<float, (int)3, (int)3, (int)0, (int)3, (int)3> > ::determinant const" is undefined in device code

voxelize.cu(301): error: calling a __host__ function("Eigen::MatrixBase< ::Eigen::Matrix<float, (int)3, (int)3, (int)0, (int)3, (int)3> > ::determinant const") from a __global__ function("MeshIterKernel") is not allowed
```

and a few more rows of that same log.

I am pretty sure that Eigen is supported since I haven't gotten any errors for other Eigen functions. I see warnings about **device** and **host** annotations ignored when compiling, but haven't seen determinant in one of those.

```
./Eigen/src/Core/Block.h(341): warning: __host__ annotation is ignored on a function("BlockImpl_dense") that is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration

./Eigen/src/Core/Block.h(341): warning: __device__ annotation is ignored on a function("BlockImpl_dense") that is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration

./Eigen/src/Core/Transpose.h(66): warning: __host__ annotation is ignored on a function("Transpose") that is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration

./Eigen/src/Core/Transpose.h(66): warning: __device__ annotation is ignored on a function("Transpose") that is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration
```

Here is part of the code that produces error.

```
__device__
bool Philipp(Vector3f A, Vector3f B, Vector3f C, Vector3f D, Vector3f P)
{
    Vector3f a = A - P, b = B - P, c = C - P, d = D - P;
    Matrix3f Da, Db, Dc, Dd;
    Da << b, c, d;
    Db << a, c, d;
    Dc << a, b, d;
    Dd << a, b, c;

    if((Da.determinant() * Dc.determinant() >= 0) && (Db.determinant() * Dd.determinant() >= 0) && (Da.determinant() * Db.determinant() <= 0))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am going to implement my own determinant function if this keep on happening.

**EDIT:**
This is the minimal code I can reduce to reproduce the issue.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

__device__
bool Foo()
{
    Vector3f a, b, c;
    Matrix3f Da;
    a << 1,2,3;
    b << 2,5,7;
    c << 6,1,8;
    Da << a, b, c;
    return Da.determinant() >= 0;
}

__global__ 
void Kernel()
{
    Foo();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Kernel<<<1,1>>>();
    return 0;
}
```

I have my Eigen folder extracted right in the working directory, and included it with

```
nvcc add.cu -I .
```

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve] and supply that here? Also, just to make sure, you did search for the error message online to form an understanding, right?

Comment: Querying the error message online only gives me the results on how to solve compiling Eigen with CUDA support, but most of my Eigen functions worked well. Also, feeding google the warning message leads me to a bunch of results on how to suppress the warnings (-Wall).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem recently. I think this is probably because the determinant() function (and maybe some other functions) is not defined as a CUDA device function in the Eigen library.

Adding **EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC** before the **determinant()** function in **Eigen/src/LU/Determinant.h** should solve this. I tried this and it worked.

The following code shows part of Determinant.h.

```
/** \lu_module
  *
  * \returns the determinant of this matrix
  */
template<typename Derived>
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC   //←← add here
inline typename internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar MatrixBase<Derived>::determinant() const
{
  eigen_assert(rows() == cols());
  typedef typename internal::nested_eval<Derived,Base::RowsAtCompileTime>::type Nested;
  return internal::determinant_impl<typename internal::remove_all<Nested>::type>::run(derived());
}
```